# How to run an app requiring admin privileges on standard user so that the user does not know the admin password?

Tags: powershell, elevated-privileges

I want two applications requiring a Windows administrator privileges to be run from a standard user account.

The standard user account is my child's account. I want her to be able to automatically run:

- MSI Afterburner (with a customized profile that corrects nVidia's voltage curve = does undervolting, saves energy, stabilazes GPU clock, improves user experience in games (increased FPS, shorter and more stable time-frame), subtracts 10+ C from GPU = silence)
- FanControl (an app to control case, CPU and GPU fans to keep their temperatures under full control)

Here is what made up:
Keep the admin password in an ecrypted form - so that my doughter cannot read it - in a file and invoke these two from a script run on user logon.

I use PowerShell to achieve it:

```
"password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "C:\pass.sec"
```

Then I want to use that password and an administraotrs group member user to invoke an exe file also from the PowserShell script. Because I got stuck, I am still on the stage of interactive issuing commands.

Here is what I have reached so far:

```
#use the ecrypted file and retrieve the password from it. The goal is to use AES (using a randomed matrix to encrypt and decrypt the password). Pretty easy but let's leave simple for now.
$f = "c:\pass.sec"
$p = Get-Content $f | ConvertTo-SecureString

#an admin group member created earlier by the system admin (me)
$u = ".\app"

#create a user credential object
$k = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($u,$p)

#use the credentials to run another powershell instance as an administrator
Start-Process powershell -Credential $k -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -Command &{Start-Process -filepath "powershell" -verb runas}'
```

Above works perfectly well and does what is needed however using the same to run FanControl.exe (with its full path, of course), does not run the app. Any clue why? I give up and I have no experience to troubleshoot it further. Counting on your happy to help.

```
#this does not work as desired at all
Start-Process powershell -Credential $k -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process -filepath "C:\Program Files\FanControl\fancontrol.exe" -verb runas}'
```

I have figured that maybe I should run fancontrol.exe as an argument from the elevated powershell instance invoked with this

```
Start-Process powershell -Credential $k -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -Command &{Start-Process -filepath "powershell" -verb runas}'
```

but the systax defeated me.

Could you give me a hand?

As described above...

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: With `-Command` (implied for `powershell.exe`, whereas `-File` is implied for `pwsh.exe`), any `"` characters that are to be preserved as part of the PowerShell code to execute must be _escaped_, as ``\"``. E.g., from `cmd.exe` the following calls are _roughly_ equivalent (there are differences in argument and exit-code handling): `powershell -File "C:\path with spaces\script.ps1"` and `powershell "& \"C:\path with spaces\script.ps1\""`. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: In concrete terms: You need `Start-Process powershell -Credential $k -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command Start-Process -filepath \"C:\Program Files\FanControl\fancontrol.exe\" -verb runas'`